# Problem re-installing NodeJS and NPM on Windows10

Tags: node.js, windows-10, npm-install, failed-installation

I am a novice with node.js and npm. I wanted to use purgecss npm plugin so tried to update and upgrade my node
Downloaded v11.1 and installed it but after that Its broken now and I can't figure out its log file either
[image]

Here is the npm-debug.log file with it. Please tell me in simple and plain words how to fix this node installation problem

[image]

Comment: What exactly did you download and install?

Comment: node-v11.1.0-x64 and installed it

Comment: The installer from Nodejs.org?  Or, some other installer?

Comment: Yes it is from https://nodejs.org/dist/v11.1.0/node-v11.1.0-x64.msi

Comment: I already had older version of node installed so was trying to upgrade it

Comment: And, you uninstalled Node.js and installed it again?  Did you install to the same path as last time?  Is there a chance you had the 32-bit version before?

Comment: Not uninstalled but just installed it over the previous version, I thought that it must upgrade it

Comment: Sure, normally, but you have a problem.  You should do some basic debugging of this issue.  If you can't be bothered to first try uninstalling and reinstalling, I don't know what you expect us to do from here.

Comment: I think the installer first uninstalled the previous version itself so should I repeat it again

Comment: even after uninstall and new install, same thing happens

Comment: I have un-installed the node and re-installed it again but the same errors as above

Comment: Did you try deleting all `node_modules`?  https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2246  (You might have to do this in the global location, in your case.)

Comment: I deleted the node_modules folder in my program files where node was installed and then repaired it as it stopped working. But still the same error screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the Environment Paths somehow got messed up on the re-install of Node latest version.
So these are the Environment Variables paths settings that worked for me
Now my settings that worked for me looks like this

USER VARIABLES
[image]

SYSTEM VARIABLES
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your having a problem try to update node.js (I did for 3 days). Try Give NVM (Node Version Manager) a try.

Do the following in **this** order:

1. curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
2. command -v nvm
3. nvm install node
4. node -v

node -v will show you that your node.js is updated.

Comment: node -v is giving me versions and everything. I found the problem was in the Windows Environmental Paths when I reinstalled it. I think they somehow messed up